# Get Facebook group name from group ID/URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

If I have a Facebook group ID and URL, like `https://www.facebook.com/groups/731045410887897/`, how do I get the group name?

This is public information. I can see the group name if I go to the URL, even if there is a login popup on top. In the above case it's "Easy Air Fryer Recipes"

I used to be able to crawl the page and look up the title element. However, Facebook now just gives a login page if I make the call programmatically.

I'm not seeing this option in the graph API.

Comment: If you're not at least a member of the group, then you can't get this info via API.

Comment: Even though it's public info that I can get from the webpage?

Comment: Yes. "Public" via the UI has not meant "publicly accessible via API" for _most_ stuff that is on Facebook, since a very long time.